# Surjectivity of multiplicative map (in more specific case)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

(I have asked the question  [Surjectivity of multiplicative map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361385/surjectivity-of-multiplicative-map). I ask here the more specific case.)

Let $S$ be a smooth complex algebraic surface, and $D$ be a divisor on $S$ such that $D^2>0$ and $H^i(S, \mathcal{O}(nD)) = 0 $ for all $i > 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ ($D$ is not necessarily ample , but nef & big).

Write $W = S \times S$ and the coherent sheaf $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{O}_{S}(nD) \boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{S}(nD)$ on $W$.
Suppose that we have an exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow H^0(W, \mathcal{G} \otimes I_{\Delta}^{n}) \rightarrow H^0(W, \mathcal{G}) \xrightarrow{\varphi} H^0(W, \mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{O}_W/I_{\Delta}^{n}) \rightarrow H^1(W, \mathcal{G} \otimes I_{\Delta}^{n}) \rightarrow 0.$$
where $\Delta$ is a diagonal embedding $S \hookrightarrow S \times S = W$ and $I_{\Delta}$ is an idela sheaf of $\Delta$.

By the Kunneth formula, we have $H^0(W, \mathcal{G}) = H^0(S, \mathcal{O}_S(nD)) \otimes H^0(S, \mathcal{O}_S(nD)).$
So, $\varphi$ can be regarded as a multiplicative map followed by some inflation into infinitesimal neighborhood.

*I want to show the surjectivity of the map $\varphi$, or equivalently, the vanishing of $H^1(W, \mathcal{G} \otimes I_{\Delta}^{n})$ (under the action of $\mathfrak{S}_2$ in practice) for sufficiently large $n$.*

The sheaf $\mathcal{O}_W/I_{\Delta}^{n}$ has a filtration by $I^k_{\Delta}/I^{n}_{\Delta}$ with associated graded factors
$$ I^k_{\Delta}/I^{k+1}_{\Delta} \simeq Sym^k(\Omega_S), \ 0 \leq k \leq n-1. $$

So, I think we have to check the surjectivity on each $H^0(S, \mathcal{O}(2nD)\otimes Sym^{k}(\Omega_S))$ (is it right?).
I have shown $H^i(S, \mathcal{O}_S(2nD) \otimes Sym^k(\Omega_S)) = 0$ for all $i > 0$ and $0 \leq k \leq n-1$.

I found the paper of Mark L. Green [Koszul cohomology and the geometry of projective varieties](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214438426)(I read part of it) which says that:

> Corollary(4.e.4)(The Explicit $H^0$ Lemma). Let $C$ be a smooth curve of genus $g$, and $L \rightarrow C$ and $M \rightarrow C$ analytic line bundles.
> Assume that $\deg L \leq \deg M$ and that $|L|$ is base-point free.
> If either
> $$\deg L + \deg M \geq 4g + 2$$
> or
> $$\deg M = 2g+1, \deg L = 2g$$
> then the multiplication map
> $$H^0(C, L) \otimes H^0(C, M) \rightarrow H^0(C, L \otimes M)$$
> is surjectictive.

My question is that *can we generalize this statement to the case of surfaces?
How can I prove the surjectivity of $\varphi$ ?*

I appreciate any advice, answers, or references.